# how to display data that begins outside the Scale Limit

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Currently I have this visual and it works fine when my scale limit:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels=date_format("%b%y"),
limits = c(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2018-02-01")))
```

It's set to display a large range. In this example note that these bars both have start dates at Feb '16. See below for the pics.

When I set my scale limit to:

```
limits = c(
      as.POSIXct("2016-07-01"),
      as.POSIXct("2018-02-01"))
```

The data that began before July '16 doesn't appear, even though it's still relevant. You can see what I'm getting at here.

I still want to see the bar even if the date range cuts off the beginning.

Here are both of my charts in one pic. Before is on top, after is on bottom.

[image: Charts]

Comment: you can use `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(as.POSIXct("2016-07-01"), as.POSIXct("2018-02-01"))`, which keeps data outside limit.

Comment: You're a BOSS!!! This worked great!

Answer (score 1):

This worked great. Cartesian FTW.

```
ggplot(dataset,aes(x=datetime_start, y=dataset$Product, color=Stage, order = - as.numeric(Stage))) +
geom_segment(aes(x=From,xend=To,yend=dataset$Product), size=10) +
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels=date_format("%b%y")) +
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(as.POSIXct("2016-07-01"), as.POSIXct("2018-02-01"))) +
```